# Refresh page when row inserted on gridview

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have some text boxes and below a gridview, when I add a line to the grid view, joining the lines I generate the text that goes in one of the text boxes above. I need to refresh the page so that the correct text appears because it is not updated. How do I do it? I develop using DevExpress and vb .Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this code in the RowInserted or RowUpdated event of the gridview was solved

```
DevExpress.Web.ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback(Request.RawUrl)
```